# Why doesn't apt-get install back the original files of a package after I removed them?

Tags: apt, vsftpd

I initially installed the `vsftpd` using apt-get. After the installation I had a default `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file with a sample configuration that I modified. After screwing it up decided to uninstall `vsftpd` and install it back. After `apt-get remove vsftpd` the configuration file was still there.

Question 1: Why wasn't the file not removed?

I installed back `vsftpd` using `apt-get install` but the default configuration file was not created.

Question 2: Why wasn't the default configuration file not created again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1)**:  With `remove` as the `apt-get` argument, it only removes the binaries for the program, and leaves the configs alone, in case you want to install (and restore from), or transfer to another system, the configs around later.  Or if you want to just restage the software if you install a later version or such.

**(2)**: If you want the packages to reinstall their defaults, try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure [package]` or `sudo apt-get purge [package]; sudo apt-get install [package]`.  `purge` will force the removal of all configurations.  The `install` after the purge will then reinstall all the defaults.